# NGINX Plus container throwing error as nginxplus executable not found

Tags: docker, nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I am getting below error when i deploy nginxplus container:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason                 Age               From                               Message
  ----     ------                 ----              ----                               -------
  Normal   Scheduled              1m                default-scheduler                  Successfully assigned nginx-ingress-744f8c7d8-mtx5c to aks-nodepool1-39499429-1
  Normal   SuccessfulMountVolume  1m                kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  MountVolume.SetUp succeeded for volume "nginx-ingress-token-lzp54"
  Normal   Pulling                1m                kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  pulling image "**.azurecr.io/nginxplus:v2"
  Normal   Pulled                 1m                kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  Successfully pulled image "**.azurecr.io/nginxplus:v2"
  Warning  BackOff                56s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  Back-off restarting failed container
  Normal   Pulled                 41s (x3 over 1m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  Container image "**.azurecr.io/nginxplus:v2" already present on machine
  Normal   Created                40s (x4 over 1m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  Created container
  Warning  Failed                 40s (x4 over 1m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  Error: failed to start container "nginxplus": executable not found in $PATH
  Warning  FailedSync             28s (x8 over 1m)  kubelet, aks-nodepool1-39499429-1  Error syncing pod
```

I have used nginxplus dockerfile from https://www.nginx.com/blog/deploying-nginx-nginx-plus-docker/

I have used ingress controller file from https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress/blob/master/install/deployment/nginx-plus-ingress.yaml

Pod Logs updated:

This is what i get when i try to retrieve pod logs.

```
$ kubectl get pods -n nginx-ingress
NAME                            READY     STATUS             RESTARTS   AGE
nginx-ingress-744f8c7d8-mtx5c   0/1       CrashLoopBackOff   39         2h  

$ kubectl logs nginx-ingress-744f8c7d8-mtx5c -n nginx-ingress
failed to open log file "/var/log/pods/e6ed4c91-0fb7-11e8-b1bc-0a58ac1f1223/nginxplus_39.log": open /var/log/pods/e6ed4c91-0fb7-11e8-b1bc-0a58ac1f1223/nginxplus_39.log: no such file or directory
```

Please help!!

Comment: Hi can share the logs the `nginx` pod? It would help fix this situation.

Comment: @Ahab updated please check above

Comment: Ok so there is no log file. Its just not working at all. Have you tried https://github.com/nginxinc/kubernetes-ingress

Comment: Yes We had used this as well just that we had not sued Makefile utility to build the image. We will give a try by using this

Answer (score 0):

The nginx plus dockerfile you referenced cannot be used for the nginx ingress controller.

You should use [the nginx plus ingress controller docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/nginxdemos/nginx-ingress/) instead.

Comment: Yes will follow the steps mentioned here. Thank you